# How to test if any set of pairs contains elements of other list? no matter order of elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to detect if a set of pairs, for example `a={{2,5},{6,3},{1,4},{8,7}}`
contains a given pair, for example `tabu={{4,1},{2,6}}` but don´t be relevant the order inside pair (pair `{i,j}` is equal to `{j,i}`), so in this case.... YES!!! "a has an element of tabu.

That´s the only target.

So, Are there any function to do this directly?

---

I was thinking in a variable `tabustatus = True` if the big contains any pair of `tabu`, or `tabustatus = False` otherwise. Ordering previously the pairs for avoid the sort issue(no matter) any similar to:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {5, 2}};
tabu = {{2, 6}, {4, 1}};
asortg = Table[Sort[a[[i]], Greater], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
asortl = Table[Sort[a[[i]], Less], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
tabusortg = Table[Sort[tabu[[i]], Greater], {i, 1, Length[tabu]}];
tabusortl = Table[Sort[tabu[[i]], Less], {i, 1, Length[tabu]}];
Print["a...........", a];
Print["a - Greater.", asortg];
Print["a - Less....", asortl];
Print["----------------------"];
Print["tabu...........", tabu];
Print["tabu - Greater.", tabusortg];
Print["tabu - Less.....", tabusortl];
Print["----------------------"];
tabustatus = False;
Do[Do[Print["i..", i, "  j..", j];If[asortl[[i]] == tabusortl[[j]], Print[asortl[[i]], " - ", tabusortl[[j]]]; tabustatus = True; Break[], False]; If[tabustatus == True, Break[]], {i, 1, Length[asortl]}]; If[tabustatus == True, Break[]], {j, 1, Length[tabu]}];
Print["Tabu Status...", tabustatus];
```

In this case, I would need to add any `Breaks[]` to exit `If`... `Do`...`Do`... without continue searching,... since one time one is found,... `TABUSTATUS=TRUE`, We don´t need to continue searching.

Any faster and less tedious alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Or @@ (MemberQ[Sort /@ tabu, #] & /@ Sort /@ a)

(* True *)
```

There are *many* ways to do this, above is fine for reasonable lists sizes, if your lists are large, there are faster methods.

Comment: Could you put the complete solution? because the other answer were delted. I think that There was an error, as you can see in http://sensa.square7.ch/hgjkhfhgf0.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke: Not sure if you're commenting @ me, mine gives correct `True` for the data in that image. Other answer was not mine...

Comment: Yes, I only refered to whats before OR@@....  to be a function.

For other visitors.The solution seems to be 

includes[list_, tabu_] := 
 Or @@ (MemberQ[Sort /@ tabu, #] & /@ Sort /@ list)

 ....as rasher said, and other colleague puts other deleted answer.

The other was erroneus, I think , as you see in http://sensa.square7.ch/hgjkhfhgf0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
containsTabu = ContainsAny[Sort /@ #, Sort /@ #2]&;

containsTabu[a, tabu]
```

> True

```
containsTabu[a, {{5,6},{2,3}}]
```

> False

Answer (score 0):

If you have large lists, than a faster approach is to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest). Moreover, if you are checking membership with the same list multiple times, than this approach should be much faster. First, the OP example:

```
nf = Nearest[Sort /@ a -> "Index"];

!MatchQ[nf[Sort /@ tabu, {1, 0}], {{} ..}]
```

> True

Now, for a much larger example:

```
a = RandomInteger[10^4, {10^6, 2}];
tabu = RandomInteger[10^8, {10^5, 2}];

nf = Nearest[Sort /@ a -> "Index"]; //AbsoluteTiming
!MatchQ[nf[Sort /@ tabu, {1, 0}], {{} ..}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.385679, Null}
>
> {0.042875, False}

A comparison with the other answers:

```
With[{s = Sort /@ tabu},
    Or @@ (MemberQ[s, #] & /@ Sort /@ a[[;;10^3]])
] //AbsoluteTiming (* ciao *)

containsTabu = ContainsAny[Sort/@#, Sort/@#2]&;

containsTabu[a, tabu] //AbsoluteTiming (* kglr *)
```

> {25.0451, False}
>
> {2.76778, False}